# Convert from JSON object to expando object in c#

Tags: c#, json, converters, expandoobject

I have a JSON object, something like:

```js
var jsonObject = {"att1" : "val1","att2" : "val2","att3" : "val3","att4" : "val4"}
```

I need to convert the same into an ExpandoObject.

I tried something like:

```csharp
var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(jsonObject, 
                                                                 expConverter);
```

But it is not giving me the desired result.

Can someone help me get the result?

Comment: "But It is not giving the result" doesn't tell us what *does* happen. Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, including expected and actual results.

Comment: You should not use `dynamic`. Just typecast the whole thing to `List<ExpandoObject>`

Comment: You are trying to convert a non array JSON into a List<>. If you looked at the error that your code produces when run, you would see that the error is telling you that you are trying to do that

Comment: Additionally, the JSON indeed isn't an array, so it won't convert to one in c# :)

Comment: `dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonObject, expConverter);` works just fine...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```csharp
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonObject, expConverter);
```

Your JSON object isn't an array, so you can't serialize to a `List<>`. Just serialize to the object directly instead.

Comment: **Hint:** If you're exploring that in **LinqPad,** you need to convert it to an object before you dump it, like: `((object)obj).Dump();` That will show the entire object.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for deeply nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues, preventing the code to work:

1. The syntax of your jsonObject declaration is not correct. Declare it as a string and inside the string use the escape "backslash + double quote" for every double quote:
   `var jsonObject = "{\"att1\": \"val1\",\"att2\": \"val2\",\"att3\": \"val3\",\"att4\": \"val4\"}";`
2. Then, when using `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters`, instead of `List<ExpandoObject>` it needs to be `ExpandoObject` in the type argument, because an ExpandoObject is inside already a dictionary (not a list):
   `dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonObject, expConverter);`

The following code fixes the two issues mentioned above and displays the key/value pairs on screen:

```cs
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

void Main()
{
  // 1. this needs to be a string
  var jsonObject =  
    "{\"att1\": \"val1\",\"att2\": \"val2\",\"att3\": \"val3\",\"att4\": \"val4\"}";

  var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();

  // 2. the correct type argument is ExpandoObject
  dynamic obj = 
              JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonObject, expConverter);

  // display the keys and values on screen
  foreach (var o in obj)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{o.Key}, {o.Value}");
  }
}
```

The output is:

> att1, val1
>
> att2, val2
>
> att3, val3
>
> att4, val4

**Note:** You can easily convert the expando to a dictionary (internally it already is an `IDictionary`) like:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(obj);
```

That allows to do a `dict.Dump()` in LinqPad (not supported with ExpandoObject)

---

If you're trying it out in LinqPad press <kbd>F4</kbd> and add the NUGET package `Json.NET` (if you don't have the paid version of LinqPad, NUGET function is limited there - try `Rock.Core.Newtonsoft` in this case).